# Java program looping help! I need to restart the program via a y/n input

Tags: java, loops, restart

Okay so I made a program but I need to be able to restart the program by asking if the user wants to try again y/n? But I can't seem to loop it correctly. Help me! P.S sorry for formatting.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Tester
{...

    ...}
System.out.println("y/n?");
String playagain = in.nextLine();
if (playagain == "y")
play = true;
else
play = false;
}

}
}
```

Comment: Not that it solves anything, but you don't have to use `if (condition) value = true; else value = false;` instead you can write `value = condition;`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
if ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(playagain))
```

Don't use == to compare Strings.  All that does is compare reference values.  You want equals(): it compares String contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String s;
while (!(s = in.nextLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {       
    // do stuff
    System.out.println("---");      
}
```

Added a way to quit the game by typing "q", every other input restarts the game with the new word, but you could switch that to y/n as well.
You can put all the rest of your logic inside the while loop or even call a method doing the logic inside it.